# How to pass an argument from a bash script to 'x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c'?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Let's say I've got this script :

```
x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c 'echo hello > ~/text'
```

I call it foo.sh and make it executable.

If I execute this script I'll have a text file in my home folder containing the word 'hello'.

Now if I modify it to this :

```
x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c 'echo $1 > ~/text'
```

... and I execute it in a terminal like this :

```
./foo.sh hello
```

I get a text file in my home folder containing nothing.

foo.sh receives 'hello' as the first and only argument ($1).
So why doesn't bash receive it ? Is there a way to pass one or several arguments from foo.sh to bash ?

I tried to store the argument inside a variable name and then export it but it didn't change the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man bash`

```
   -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the
             first  non-option  argument  command_string.   If  there are
             arguments after the command_string, they are assigned to the
             positional parameters, starting with $0.
```

So you can do

```
x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c 'echo $0 > ~/text' "$1"
```

or (if you prefer to preserve the "usual" numbering of parameters)

```
x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c 'echo $1 > ~/text' _ "$1"
```

where `_` can be replaced with any dummy variable of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash -c 'echo $1 > ~/text'`, `$1` was expanded in `bash -c` process, not in your script. You need to pass the original `$1` to `bash -c`:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c 'echo \$1 > ~/text' bash $1"
```

Comment: Why complicate things? Why not just use double quotes: `x-terminal-emulator -e bash -c "echo $1 > ~/text"`. Also, I can't get yours to work, it gives an error, but I don't understand why escaping the dollar would help. That just tells `bash -c` to echo _its_ `$1` as far as I can tell.

Comment: @terdon: I got error unknown option `-c` with `xfce4-terminal -e bash -c 'echo \$@;sleep 10' _ 123`, so wrapping command in the whole string can be more portable. And some time you only need using several of parameters, so `"bash -c 'echo \$@ > ~/text' bash $1 $2 $3"` is easier.

Comment: I get an error with this one :). In any case, why would escaping the dollar help?

Comment: @terdon: it prevents `$1` from being expanded by parent shell. Example in `"bash -c 'echo $1 $2 $3 > ~/text' bash $2 $1 $3"`, then `$1` inside `bash -c` isn't `$1` that you passed to it.

Comment: No, of course not, but the OP wants the `$1` from the shell script, they're not actually passing anything to the `bash -c` process. They want to get `$1` as given on the command line. I just don't see the point of passing `$1` again since it's already defined.

Comment: @terdon: The OP asked `So why doesn't bash receive it`, how do you understand that statement? For me, It seems that the OP didn't understand why `$1` expanded to nothing in his child `bash`. And he confused between arguments passed to the script with the arguments passed to `bash -c`. Unless like I understood, we simply need `x-terminal-emulator -e "echo $1 > ~/text"` and everything is done.